# Replacing parts of the body whilst preserving HTML

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to find & replace parts of a HTML body. I have managed to do this but not using HTMLbody so once I run the macro the body of the email becomes plaintext.

This is what I tried initially:

```
Sub ReplaceText()

Dim Insp As Inspector
Dim obj As Object

    Set Insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem

    obj.Body = Replace(obj.Body, "TEXT TO FIND", "TEXT TO REPLACE WITH")

    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Insp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Since this did not work, I am trying to use the WordEditor. My current code does not do anything.

```
Public Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection
    On Error Resume Next

    Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
            If objInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
                Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
                Set objWord = objDoc.Application
                Set objSel = objWord.Selection

                With objSel.Find
                 .Text = "This is an online meeting"
                 .Replacement.Text = "TEST TEST"
                 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With

            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Set objInsp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Regardless of whether it helps, remove On Error Resume Next.  "... is the most commonly used and misused form.  It instructs to VBA to essentially ignore the error and resume execution on the next line of code. It is very important to remember that On Error Resume Next does not in any way "fix" the error." http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `.body` with `.HTMLBody` in your original function and that should work.

Edit - This is the function that works for me.

```
Sub ReplaceText()

Dim Insp As Inspector
Dim obj As Object

Set Insp = Application.ActiveInspector
Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem

obj.HTMLBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, "TEXT TO FIND", "TEXT TO REPLACE WITH")

Set obj = Nothing
Set Insp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This gives error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: It doesn't on mine? Did you change both `.body`s?

Answer (score 0):

How about selecting the msg

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem

    '//- Selected msg
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If olItem.Class = olMail Then
            olItem.HTMLBody = Replace(olItem.HTMLBody, "TEXT TO FIND", "TEXT TO REPLACE WITH")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```